# Sending a Vector in Winsock

Tags: c++, vector, winsock, send

I am trying to send a full vector from the server  to a client using Winsock. Up to now I have been working, sending chars with the function send, defined by Winsock in the example they provide(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx). The thing is that I have entered in the definition of send and obviously is only defined to send chars. So my question is if there is any way of sending a vector from the server to the client. If there is, how would you implement it?

Comment: You cannot send a vector directly, you have to serialize the vector into an array of chars, send the chars, and on the receiver deserialize the chars into a vector.

Comment: so there is no way? not even creating a send_vec function based on the send one?

Comment: _You_ may create a `send_vec` function. The clue is to transform your vector into a string and transform the string back into a vector. This transformation process is called "serialisation/deserialisation", it's not trivial. Google _vector c++ serialize_

Comment: @19mike95 Michael **didn't** say that there is no way. He said that you can't do it **directly**. So, yes, you can make a function `send_vec`, that serializes the vector into an array of `char`s, and sends it to the client, in a format, understandable to client.

Comment: Presumably, you could subclass vector and design a 'NetVector' class that has methods that take streams as parameters and read/write themselves.

Comment: @MartinJames, while I do not neccessarily disagree with that, prepare for the storm of negative comments :)

Comment: Ok, so serialization is the way. The vector i want to send is a vector of messages, where message is a struct with id, message and time, will this fact bring any issue?

Comment: @SergeyA lol.............